# deleting unwanted xml nodes

Tags: xml, regex, r

I have a bunch of .xml files with nodes that are causing uncessesary complications.  I would like to remove these nodes but ensure that thier children are preserved (not the heirarchical structure but the data).  Eventually I want to take the data from each .xml and build a dataframe.  It seems like xmlTreeParse along with xmlToList will help but the latter only works well with a flat structure.  I have played around with unlisting the output from xmlToList and then converting it a dataframe but the output is a bit funky.

I thought about simply writing a function to go through all the files and delete all tags that I don't want however I don't know how to do this in R.

ANy suggestions?

Comment: It would probably help if you supplied examples of the xml before and after the requested changes.

Comment: Here is an extract of the xml I am starting with: 
<?xml version='1.0' ?><swes id="swes"><formName>SWES_2</formName><formVersion>0.0.2</formVersion><StartTime>2010-06-26T18:19:02.598</StartTime><EndTime>2010-06-26T18:21:11.742</EndTime><P0_SurveyorName>Melissa</P0_SurveyorName><P0a_DeviceNumber>3</P0a_DeviceNumber><P1_Date>2010-06-26</P1_Date><P2_District>1</P2_District><poop><P3a_Village1>dzemeni</P3a_Village1><P4_HousholdNumber /><P5_VisitNumber>2</P5_VisitNumber></poop><P6_HouseholdLocation /><P10.1_PhoneNumber>684656856</P10.1_PhoneNumber><Q4_EducationEver>0</Q4_EducationEver></swes>

Comment: I want to simply remove the <poop> </poop> tags

Comment: May be opening a connection to each file and using gsub("<poop>",,files)?

Comment: `gsub` is definitely NOT the thing you need. Substitution of "<poop>" or "</poop>" tags with "" will not remove text within "<poop>"s. You need XML parser, i.e. XML package available in CRAN repos. Sadly, I haven't got much experience in R's XML parsing features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple to do in XSLT.  Add this to the identity transform:

```
<xsl:template match="poop">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Using regular expressions on XML [hastens the coming of the Elder Gods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

see if this is what you are looking for, you can use `XML` package from `CRAN` for the parsing of XML documents. You can use the following tactic to get only the `<poop>` tags:

```
me<-xmlTreeParse(filename,useInternalNodes=T)
pooptags<-xpathApply(me,"//poop")
```

pooptags will contain the following information :

```
<poop>
  <P3a_Village1>dzemeni</P3a_Village1>
  <P4_HousholdNumber/>
  <P5_VisitNumber>2</P5_VisitNumber>
</poop>
```

you can paste this with the `<?xml version='1.0' ?>` using paste command in R and write it to a truncated file. or you can further extract information like P3a_Village1 from the XML file using the xpathApply like this:

```
village<-xpathApply(me,"//poop/P3a_Village1")
```

I hope the solution is what you are looking for. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I think this would be a looong way to do it so I decided to use an xslt script.  Oh well...